# Solve system of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this system:

$\pmatrix{1 & 90 & 30} = \frac{1}{1.2} \ \left( \begin{array}{c} q_u & q_m & q_d \end{array} \right)   \pmatrix{1.2 & 180 & 0 \\ 1.2 & 120 &30 \\ 1.2 &60 & 60}$

How can I solve this for $q_u$, $q_m$ and $q_d$?

ALSO - I know the answers to be

$$ q_u = .2 - \alpha \ , \ q_m = .4 + 2 \alpha \ , \ q_d = .4 - \alpha \ $$

BUT I am not sure where that alpha comes from

BTW - this is my first time posting.

Thank you!

Comment: You should take a look on how matrix multiplication works. Just multiply the two matrices on the right hand side of the equation and compare columns of the resulting matrix with the columns of the matrix on the left hand side.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how to solve?

Comment: Note that your matrix is singular, since the first row is a linear combination of the second and third rows (if we denote the rows $R_{1}, R_{2}, R_{3}$, then we see $R_{1} = 2R_{2} - R_{3}$). Hence, your answer will include a free parameter - I assume this is what is meant in the solution by $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you AWertheim this is starting to make sense. I am just wondering does this need to be solved by hand like mirgee is doing below and if so how does that alpha parameter come into play?  If it can be solved computationally can you give a hint. I cannot invert the matrix to just have the q vector on the right side. Thank you.

Comment: If you multiply out the matrices on the right-hand side, you will have a matrix equation representing a system of linear equations, as **mirgee** describes.  You can then solve it by "row-reduction" or "elimination", despite the coefficient matrix being singular.  That will reveal the presence of the "free variable.

Comment: No problem! One can solve it by hand, as mirgee suggests. An identical method is to reduce the matrix (with solutions) to reduced row echelon form via Gauss elimination, as I think is more commonly done in linear algebra classes. If that suggestion doesn't really make sense to you, however, then mirgee's method is probably the ideal way. I can elaborate more as well. Regarding the $\alpha$ parameter, it should come up when you solve the equations; you should find that you cannot solve for a unique value of $q_{d}$.

Comment: Can you work out until the alpa is revealed? I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

$ \frac {1}{1.2} \pmatrix {q_u q_m q_d}  * \pmatrix{1.2 & 180 & 0 \\ 1.2 & 120 &30 \\ 1.2 &60 & 60}=\frac {1}{1.2} \pmatrix{1.2q_u+1.2q_m+1.2q_d & 180q_u+120q_m+60q_d & 30q_m+60q_d}=\pmatrix{1 & 90 & 30}$, so

$q_u+q_m+q_d=1$

$150q_u+100q_m+50q_d=90$

$25q_m+50q_d=30$

Then you eliminate $q_u$ from the second equation:

$q_u+q_m+q_d=1$

$-50q_m-100q_d=-60$

$25q_m+50q_d=30$

Now notice that the second equation is the same as the third, just multiplied by $(-2)$, so it doesn't add any new information and we can forget about it. So we have

$q_u+q_m+q_d=1$

$5q_m+10q_d=6$

Now we have three unknowns, but only two equations. This means, we don't have enough information to find one specific solution. There will be infinitely many.

Let's try to find one: $q_d=.4$, $q_m=.4$, $q_u=.2$. But now notice - if I subtract a number from $q_u$ and add twice that to $q_m$, they will cancel out and $5q_m+10q_d=6$ still. Now I just have to make sure this new number won't mess up the first equation by adding appropriate multiple of it to $q_u$ and I'm done. Note this works only because the system is linear.

Comment: Migree and you continue a bit?  I am a little lost on how the alpha will come into play in the next steps. Thank you.

Comment: @user3609949 I edited the answer.

Comment: How do you just eliminate qu from the second equation? I see you subtract 150 from other terms but what about qu?

Comment: @user3609949 I subtracted 150 times the first equation from the second...

Answer (score 1):

If we write the system of equations as an "augmented matrix",

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|r}
1&1&1&1 \\ 150 & 100 & 50& 90 \\ 0 & 25 & 50 & 30 \\  \end{array} \right] \ \ , $$

"row-reduction" will take this to

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|r}
1&1&1&1 \\ 0 & -50 & -100& -60 \\ 0 & 25 & 50 & 30 \\  \end{array} \right] \ \ . $$

The last row can be "zeroed-out" completely, telling us that we have a dependent system,

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|r}
1&1&1&1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2& 1.2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  \end{array} \right] \ \ . $$

We are thus "free" to give $ \ q_d \ $ any value we like, and then back-substitute to find relations between $ \ q_d \ , \ q_m \ , \ $ and $ \ q_u \ $ .  (Depending upon what you choose for $ \ q_d \ $ , you will not necessarily get the answer you show, but something related.  I made a different choice than the solver of the problem apparently did, but if we *set* $ \ q_d \ = \ 0.4 \ - \ \alpha \ $ , we do get the rest of the values shown.)